# Safari text-input rendering text below input box

Tags: html, css, safari

I've run into a problem in safari where the text in my input box is rendered below the box as you can see in the image. Ive tried this in chrome and firefox and it seems to work fine so I'm not sure what there is I can change. Sorry I couldn't figure out how to separate my code blocks for the CSS and HTML, I'm new round here.
[image]

```css
.banner {
  background: #ececec;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 64px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  min-width: 1100px;
}
.search_bar {
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  width: 276px;
  color: #353a4f;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: League Spartan, helvetica;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin: 0;
}
.search_bar:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.search_bar_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 14px;
  left: 20px;
  margin: 0 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
.search_bar_icon {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  fill: #353a4f;
  top: 6px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="search_bar_wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="search_bar" placeholder="Search..." />
    <img src="imgs/Icons/search.svg" class="search_bar_icon" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you specify the version of Safari?  I tried this in Safari and even mobile Safari on the iPad and it seems fine.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm in version 9.1.3

Comment: Looks fine in CodePen, Safari Version 9.1.3: http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/zKKYxW?editors=1100

Comment: I have no idea what it was then, must've been something else in my code messing it up, just managed to fix it by specifying line height on the search bar item. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed just by specifying line-height on the input box.